# Postman use variable in body raw text not like json for HL7 message

Tags: javascript, postman

How to use variable in body RAW text ?

Hi community,

I have defined a variable in the pre-request script of my collection called “DateNow” like that :

```
var DateNow = new Date().toISOString().replace(/(.\d{3})|[^\d]/g,‘’);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable(‘DateNow’, DateNow);
```

Now i must pass this variable in the body raw text of my HL7 message like that :

```
MSH|^~&|Soft1||Soft2||{{DateNow}}||SIU^S12^SIU_S12|1dc8ed8b21d8502f2199|P|2.5.1|||||FRA|UTF-8
```

but the {{DateNow}} still remain text and not variable.

How can i do it ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have an environment file created and set while you're doing this.

You can use this in a pre-request script as an alternative:

```js
let DateNow = new Date().toISOString().replace(/(.\d{3})|[^\d]/g,'');
pm.variables.set('DateNow', DateNow);
```

It will create a variable that is used at runtime and isn't stored anywhere.

[image]